# Boost.Python build brings up an error for bjam

Tags: boost, b2

I am trying to build Boost.Python using MSVC by following [this documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/building.html).

I'm using Windows 10 x64, Visual Studio 2017 and Boost 1.73

I run bootstrap and .\b2 without errors but, when I invoke bjam, I get the following:

```
C:\Program Files\boost_1_73_0\boost_1_73_0>bjam --toolset=mscv "--prefix=C:\Program Files\boost_1_73_0\boost_1_73_0" install
warning: mismatched versions of B2 engine and core
warning: B2 engine (bjam) is 2015.07.00
warning: B2 core (at /cygdrive/c/Program Files/boost_1_73_0/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src) is 4.2-git
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/boost_1_73_0/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/tools/msvc.jam:975: in auto-detect-toolset-versions
ERROR: rule "W32_GETREG" unknown in module "msvc".
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/boost_1_73_0/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/tools/msvc.jam:2088: in load
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/boost_1_73_0/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/boost_1_73_0/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/build/toolset.jam:42: in toolset.using
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/boost_1_73_0/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:1104: in using
project-config.jam:6: in modules.load
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/boost_1_73_0/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:255: in load-config
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/boost_1_73_0/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:486: in load-configuration-files
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/boost_1_73_0/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:607: in load
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/boost_1_73_0/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/boost_1_73_0/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/boost_1_73_0/boost_1_73_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

Any idea how to solve this?